# Remove empty strings in a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I am currently working on a project of text-mining in R, with a list of lists.
I want to remove all the empty strings and the NA values of my list of lists and I haven't found a way.
My data looks like this :

```
x <- list(c("", "alteryx", "confirme", "", "", "", "ans", "", ""))
```

The principal list refered to different texts. And each text is composed of a list of all the words. So when I remove a word, it becomes an empty string. I just want to delete it definitively and so reduce the length of my text's length.

I tried many different things, such as

`stri_remove_empty_na(c(demande2[20]))` which gave me the error `Warning message:
In stri_enc_toutf8(x) : argument is not an atomic vector; coercing` and transformed my text as :
[result of stri_remove_empty_na](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNYuT.png)

So please I need your help
(and I'm sorry for my English, I'm French :))

Thanks in advance

Comment: please don't post screenshots of your data but rather a representative portion of your data using `dput(mydata)`.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know this command !
So the result for the text in example is :
``` list(c("", "alteryx", "confirme", "", "", "", "ans", "", ""))```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use `lapply` and simple subsetting:

```
x <- list(c("", "alteryx", "confirme", "", "", "", "ans", "", ""))
lapply(x, function(z){ z[!is.na(z) & z != ""]})

[[1]]
[1] "alteryx"  "confirme" "ans"
```

`lapply` applies a function to every component of a list. In this case the function is a simple subsetting function.